# IWordpress/woocommerce plugin development: Impossible to select and link jquery events to a custom form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a woocommerce plugin for a super market wordpress website.

What I want to do is to retrieve the customer's fidelity code compare it to the other information he filled in and check in the supermarket database if he is entitled to a discount or not.
My problem is that I don't know why but I can't select the fidelity code field that I created when I gave it an id that is normally displayed on the page and is unique.

On the php side, everything works normally: On the checkout page, I added a form field as follows:

```
woocommerce_form_field(
  'fidelity_code’,
  array(
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => __('Fidelity code', 'my—plugin-woo'),
      'class' => array('form-row', 'form-row-wide'),
      'id' => 'fidelity_code',
      'required' => false,
  )
```

Now in my jQuery script file, when I do something silly like :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  $("#fidelity_code").on("change", function () {
    console.log("It's work"); //Does not work
  });
});
```

it doesn't work. But if I do it on a native woocommerce field (for example the first name field), it works

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $("#billing_first_name").on("change", function () {
    console.log("It's work"); //works!!!
  });
});
```

I'm thinking that if it works on a native field, then the problem is not with jQuery. So please help me to understand.

I've tried to change the jquery version.
I've tried to use no conflict jQuery
I've tried to change $ sign by jQuery first then by another variable name like $j
I've tried to use classes instead of ids but the code below does not add the class 'fidelity_code' to the field but to its parent. I reassure you for the id, it adds it to the field

```
woocommerce_form_field(
  'fidelity_code’,
  array(
      'type' => 'text',
      'label' => __('Fidelity code', 'my—plugin-woo'),
      'class' => array('form-row', 'form-row-wide', 'fidelity_code'),
      'id' => 'fidelity_code',
      'required' => false,
  )
```

Comment: I reproduced your issue in a custom shortcode, but it works fine.

Comment: really? The fidelity code input works

Comment: Which short code? Can I see your code please?

Comment: Ok! I'm checking it

Comment: Even your code doesn't work for me. That means that the problem is probably elsewhere

Comment: It might be possible. Can you put your whole code for that custom field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution or rather the problem

I don't know why but it seems that the right way to add jquery events to woocommerce is:

```
 $(document).on(eventName, Selector, function () {
        //Do your stuff here
    });
```

So my code look like this right now:

```
 $(document).on("change", "#fidelity_code", function () {
        console.log("It works");  //It really works now
    });
```